# Using a service account and JSON key which is sent to you to upload data into google cloud storage

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I wrote a python script that uploads files from a local folder into Google cloud storage.

I also created a *service account* with sufficient permission and tested it on my computer using that service account JSON key and it worked.

Now I send the code and JSON key to someone else to run but the authentication fails on her side.

Are we missing any authentication through GCP UI?

```
def config_gcloud():
    subprocess.run(
        [
            shutil.which("gcloud"),
            "auth",
            "activate-service-account",
            "--key-file",
            CREDENTIALS_LOCATION,
        ]
    )
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_LOCATION)
    return storage_client


def file_upload(bucket, source, destination):
    storage_client = config_gcloud()
    ...
```

The error happens in the config_cloud and it says it is expecting str, path, ... but gets NonType.
As I said, the code is fine and works on my computer. How anotehr person can use it using JSON key which I sent her?She stored Json locally and path to Json is in the code.

Comment: Will this code run on your personal computer at the end? WIll run on GCP? Elsewhere?

Comment: Why are you running `gcloud` as part of your program? `CREDENTIALS_LOCATION` is the path to the service account JSON key file. Setting up the CLI is not necessary if you are specifying the credentials in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREDENTIALS_LOCATION is None instead of the correct path, hence it complaining about it being NoneType instead of str|Path.

Also you don't need that gcloud call, that would only matter for gcloud/gsutil commands, not python client stuff.

And please post the actual stacktrace of the error next time, not just a misspelled interpretation of it.